How to detect Android Virtualization Framework (AVF) support?
While I was reading https://source.android.com/docs/core/virtualization, I was curious if there is any way to detect if an android device has AVF support. There seems to be some lists of devices with this feature, like https://x.com/MishaalRahman/status/1748530686955331665, but they are not comprehensive enough.
So, how can I detect if my device supports AVF? My device is Redmi K70 Pro with a Snapdragon 8 gen 3 SoC. I know some devices with this SoC have this feature, but not sure about mine.

If you followed your first link down a few times you would have come to this:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/modules/Virtualization/+/refs/heads/main/libs/framework-virtualization/README.md#detecting-avf-support
The code provided is only valuable to those either building system level APKs or related products due to additional permissions.

Note that they are all @SystemApi and require the restricted android.permission.MANAGE_VIRTUAL_MACHINE permission, so they are not available to third party apps. In Android 14 the permission was available only to privileged apps; in Android 15 it is available to all preinstalled apps. On both versions it can also be granted to other apps via adb shell pm grant for development purposes.

